# script para automação de instalação de impressoras

Tags: windows, script, batch, impressora, vbs

Boa tarde pessoal, eu tenho em meu ambiente um servidor de impressão com um total de 63 impressoras instaladas e compartilhadas na rede, eu gostaria de um script para automatização da instalação destas impressoras nas maquinas da empresa, até agora eu fiz o script abaixo em .bat, mas ele so esta instalando 1 impressora, a nao ser que eu repita o bloco do codigo 63 vezes para fazer com cada uma eu queria uma forma de automatiza-lo para instalar todas as impressoras do servidor de impressao (verificando se as mesmas estão instaladas antes de instalar para nao instalar mais de 1 vez) mas nao consegui pensar numa sintaxe e nao quero ter que repetir este bloco de codigo 63 vezes

```
SET IMPRESSORA=\\HOSTNAME_SERVIDOR\COLOR


wmic printer get name /value | findstr /I /E "%IMPRESSORA%"


IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 Rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n %IMPRESSORA%
```

Comment: Esse "COLOR" é o nome de uma impressora que você usou como teste no seu Script?

Comment: isso, é um exemplo de uma das impressoras

Answer (score 1):

Seria bom você criar um VBS

Dentro do VBS você pode fazer um loop como o abaixo:

```
Do While X > -1
  'Aqui dentro você executa os blocos que você já fez
  set objSh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  objSh.Run "cmd /k Seus comandos", 0

  X = X - 1
Loop
```

Algo do tipo assim deve servir para o seu caso, se precisar procure por VBScript, vulgo VBS.

Comment: Aonde sõ definida as variavels ???? Não e um loop em cima de `int` mas sim de `string` ! `X = X - 1` teu loop nunca vai funcionar !!!

Comment: Só se tu setta ele a 63 no começo ! :)

Comment: As variáveis você define fora do loop, eu só dei um exemplo de como pode ser feito, não foi uma coisa completa. E o loop funciona sim sendo integer pois eu utilizo ele, é que no meu caso eu utilizo ele mesmo setado como X = 10 e depois vou fazendo X = X -1, como eu disse é um exemplo, mude para o que você precisa.

Comment: entendi sim ! esse loop vai funcionar por valor numerica más no caso as impressoras não são numeros mas sim string !

Answer (score 1):

Assim !

```
@echo off
set "$impressoras=impressora1 impressora2 impressora3 impressora4 impressora5"
set  "$server=\\0.0.0.0.0"

for %%a in (%$impressoras%) do (
  echo Tratando =^> [%%a]
  wmic printer get name /value | findstr /I /E "%%a" && echo Impressora [%%a] ja instalada || (
  echo Instalando [%%a]
  Rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n %$server%\%%a
  )
)
```

Comment: mas onde eu seto o caminho do servidor nesse script ?

Comment: Editei a resposta !

Comment: SachaDee, ele quer que o script não instale novamente uma impressora que poderá já estar instalada em alguma das máquinas.
ele quer que o script instale apenas as que não estão instaladas, em cada uma das máquinas, faltou você adicionar isso no Script

Comment: Modifiquei o script agora esta ok ! :) Foi um erro de tipo !

Answer (score 1):

Apenas crie um arquivo de texto com o nome `impressoras.txt` na área de Trabalho
e adicione nele o nome de todas as impressoras
uma em cada linha:

exemplo:

```
IMPRESSORA1
IMPRESSORA2
IMPRESSORA3
...
```

e modifique `IP-DO-SERVIDOR` pelo IP do servidor onde estão as impressoras.
eu não testei o script por não ter um servidor com 63 impressoras instaladas,
mas acho que vai funcionar. o único problema é que talvez você precise
dar um **OK** em cada um das instalações das impressoras.
talvez tenha algum parâmetro do **Rundll32** que deixe a instalação silenciosa.
segue o Script...

```
    @echo off
    mode 90,20 
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%R in (%userprofile%\desktop\impressoras.txt) do (

    set impr=%%R

    wmic printer get name /value | findstr /I /E !impr!>nul

    if !errorlevel! EQU 0 (echo.impressora !impr! j  foi instalada) Else (

    echo.
    echo. INSTALANDO: !impr! ...
    Rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n \\IP-DO-SERVIDOR\!impr!
    )
    )
    )
```

Comment: cometi alguns erros de sintaxe, mas já corrigi.